# connectedAndroidTest on multidex app is not finding any tests

Tags: android, testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I am trying to automate my build and make running our acceptance tests a part of that.

Unfortunately the gradle task `connectedAndroidTest` is reporting

> Starting 0 tests on Nexus_5X_API_25(AVD) - 7.1.1
>
> com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Nexus_5X_API_25(AVD) - 7.1.1] FAILED .
>   No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).

This does not happen when I run the tests/suite from the IDE.
I found that Android Studio is executing following commands:

```
$ adb push /path/to/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.MyApp
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.MyApp"

$ adb push /path/to/apk/app-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.MyApp.test
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.MyApp.test"

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r  -e debug false -e class com.myapp.TestSuite com.MyApp.test/com.myapp.testrunners.CreationInterceptingTestRunner
```

I know what those commands do but I do not know what `connectedAndroidTest` is doing under the hood and why it fails.

I found out that the issue has to do with multidex. At the end of the [official page about enabling multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) it reads:

> Notes:
>    * Don't use MultiDexTestRunner, which is deprecated; use AndroidJUnitRunner instead.
>    * Using multidex to create a test APK is not currently supported.

I do not understand what is mean with `create test APK` and why the adb command works.
I do not want to run the adb commands by hand as they have no reporting built in and I would need to do this all myself.

Is there any way to use `connectedAndroidTest` with multidex apps?

Comment: Hey, did you solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But we currently use spoon to run the tests as it produces nice output and uses adb. Hope this helps